# Can you use a where constraint on an inner joined table to limit results?

Tags: python, sqlite

SOLVED

```
sql = "SELECT Title, Year, TmdbId, MovieFileId, Quality " \
      "FROM Movies " \
      "INNER JOIN MovieFiles on MovieFiles.Id = Movies.MovieFileId " \
      "WHERE Quality = 7"

sql = "SELECT Title, Year, TmdbId, MovieFileId, MovieFiles.Quality " \
      "FROM Movies " \
      "INNER JOIN MovieFiles on MovieFiles.Id = Movies.MovieFileId " \
      "WHERE MovieFiles.Quality = 7"
```

Neither of these work for me, I am getting no rows returned. Quality is part of the MovieFiles table.  And Yes, rows exist that meet this criteria.

```
sql = "SELECT Title, Year, TmdbId, MovieFileId, Quality " \
      "FROM Movies " \
      "INNER JOIN MovieFiles on MovieFiles.Id = Movies.MovieFileId "
```

This works just fine, and returns the correct quality.  But, if I add the where, it does not work and just returns nothing.  Am I doing something wrong? (Using python)

Edit: Schema request

`CREATE TABLE "Movies" ("Id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "ImdbId" TEXT, "Title" TEXT NOT NULL, "TitleSlug" TEXT NOT NULL, "SortTitle" TEXT, "CleanTitle" TEXT NOT NULL, "Status" INTEGER NOT NULL, "Overview" TEXT, "Images" TEXT NOT NULL, "Path" TEXT NOT NULL, "Monitored" INTEGER NOT NULL, "ProfileId" INTEGER NOT NULL, "LastInfoSync" DATETIME, "LastDiskSync" DATETIME, "Runtime" INTEGER NOT NULL, "InCinemas" DATETIME, "Year" INTEGER, "Added" DATETIME, "Actors" TEXT, "Ratings" TEXT, "Genres" TEXT, "Tags" TEXT, "Certification" TEXT, "AddOptions" TEXT, "MovieFileId" INTEGER NOT NULL, "TmdbId" INTEGER NOT NULL, "Website" TEXT, "PhysicalRelease" DATETIME, "YouTubeTrailerId" TEXT, "Studio" TEXT, "MinimumAvailability" INTEGER NOT NULL, "HasPreDBEntry" INTEGER NOT NULL, "PathState" INTEGER NOT NULL, "PhysicalReleaseNote" TEXT, "SecondaryYear" INTEGER, "SecondaryYearSourceId" INTEGER)`

`CREATE TABLE "MovieFiles" ("Id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "MovieId" INTEGER NOT NULL, "Path" TEXT, "Quality" TEXT NOT NULL, "Size" INTEGER NOT NULL, "DateAdded" DATETIME NOT NULL, "SceneName" TEXT, "MediaInfo" TEXT, "ReleaseGroup" TEXT, "RelativePath" TEXT, "Edition" TEXT)`

Comment: are you getting any error or simply no rows returned? Can you perhaps show the schemas

Comment: @kuro no rows returned. Sorry, should have specified

Comment: can you show the schema of both the tables?

Comment: @kuro done.  Neither of these can be changed though.

Comment: I see. `Quality` is `TEXT`. So you want `where MovieFiles.Quality='7'`

Comment: Ah, yes thanks ... that solved it .. Cheers!